# SwingUtilities InvokeLater- what is considered bad practice?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, invokelater, edt

I've got a question about what would be the correct practice to use the invokeLater method of SwingUtilities.

So to begin, I'd like to confirm that I am understanding it correctly.

From what I understand, changes to the GUI must be done on the EDT, because Swing components aren't thread safe. The invokeLater method takes a Runnable as an argument, and anything contained in that runnable will be run on the EDT. Therefore any calls made to Swing components are put in a kind of queue, which are executed one at a time on the EDT.

With that out of the way, my question then is: what is good practice for using this? From what I can see there are at least two ways to do it:

1) In the `main` method, place all code, such as GUI creation, Controller creation, and even the Model creation (assuming a MVC type pattern), in a Runnable that is invoked by the invokeLater method. Of course, this is assuming that any long running tasks in the Model would be executed with a SwingWorker.

2) Place GUI creation in a invokeLater, but Controller creation and Model creation in the `main` method. Then whenever you need to access a Swing component from a Controller, you pop said code in an invokeLater method to place it on the EDT queue.

What one of these two would be considered best practice, or bad practice? And if neither of these two are good, what would be the better way to go about this?

Any info would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwingWorker isn't special, it's just some wrappers around common scenarios. It will call invokeLater on your behalf so really both cases you present are just instances of the same thing.

Just make sure you follow these two rules:
1. Don't stall the EDT
2. Perform Swing-related code on the EDT

Comment: Thanks! So when you say "peform swing related code on the EDT", for example, in case 1) in my OP, the View, Model, and Controller are all instantiated within invokeLater, so I assume they all are on the EDT. However, the Model does not execute it's code on the EDT, it creates a new SwingWorker to do the long running tasks. Is that bad practice?

Comment: @DBS: No.  Creating a new SwingWorker to do the long-running tasks is the correct practice.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks! So from what I can see there's no real 'bad' way of using it unless you are doing something really stupid like running code that doesn't have anything to do with the Swing components on the EDT and consequentially causing the GUI to hang.

Comment: if it's a method call onto a JComponent, then you need to do it from EDT, otherwise only do it on the EDT if it's instant. Model, View, Controller, probably only the view stuff on the EDT.

Answer (score 2):

That's indeed an interesting question and the accepted answer isn't fully responding it.

Both approaches you suggest are acceptable and will work fine, but I believe **the first one is better than the second** approach (do it all on the EDT, and if there is some long-running tasks do them on a SwingWorker, or a new thread if they're not related to Swing).

---

**Why?** As @ThomasKrägler pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66585250/using-swingutilities-invokelater-in-main-method):

> While you could split these tasks (model, controller and view creation) between main thread and EDT (and possibly gain a few milliseconds until the UI is first shown) it would also complicate the design of the application (multithreading is no easy topic) and litter the code base with invokeLater() calls.

Take into account that the EDT won't need to process anything until the model and controller are initialised (and thus starting the view too). So you can use the EDT to initialise them, as it won't have any negative impact on your UI (there is no UI yet).

Doing it this way, you'll save a lot of `invokeLater` calls and possible errors forgetting to call `invokeLater`. Your code will look much cleaner too.

Comment: Thank you! Been a while since I've used Java but this is great information for when I use it next.